# Spring mvc form one to many form

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

i have 3 entities Users,Department and Address. Where user can have multiple addresses. Now i have a doubt in building the form for this use case.

I can access the Department directly as it is object.But i am not getting how to refer address attributes as it is a Set.

```
class Users
{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Department dept;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<Address>(0);

  //Getters and setters
}
```

MyForm.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Contact Manager</h2>
<form:form method="post" commandName="userObject" action="addPerson.html">

    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="userObject.dept.deptName">Department Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="userObject.dept.deptName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="userObject.addresses.street">Street Address</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="userObject.addresses.street" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  

</form:form>
```

**How to access the address attribute in my jsp form using object. I am facing problem in my jsp at userObject.addresses.street**

Answer (score 2):

I would use the jstl taglib :

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and then use the foreach

and do sometihng like :

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${userObject.addresses}">
  ${item.street}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a `List` as it was a single `Object`, so you need to iterate over the `User`'s `adresses` and display the street or each one.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Contact Manager</h2>
  <form:form method="post" commandName="userObject" action="addPerson.html">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
      <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><form:label path="userObject.dept.deptName">Department Name</form:label></td>
      <td><form:input path="userObject.dept.deptName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <c:forEach var="address" items="${userObject.getAddresses()}">
        <td><form:label path="userObject.addresses.street">Street Address</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="userObject.addresses.street" />${address.street}</td> 

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  

  </form:form>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am doing like this
<c:forEach var="address" items="${person.getAddresses()}">
                            <form:select path="address.addressLocation">
                <form:options items="${meCategory}" />
            </form:select>
       </c:forEach>
       </div>

Comment: the field is not visible

Comment: Which field is not displayed exactely? What `${meCategory}` refer to?

Comment: ${meCategory} is the modelAttribute i am setting list to it.

Dropdown is not visible,When i use address.addressLocation

Comment: You make me quite confused between original post description and your recent comment.
You are using `commandName` attribute to map your bean, so what `modelAttribute` you are talking about?
Otherwise, the `<form:select><form:options /></form:select>` is used to display a list of entries from a map (The key as the value of the option and the value as the display field) so I assume it can fit with your `Address` Object no?